# Getting data with regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I've a string like this, and I need to save each value in two strings:

```
Variable 1 = 385289
Variable 2 = L1S8dM4OW0VkGhKgl0NcGA%3d%3d

<<<385289<<<L1S8dM4OW0VkGhKgl0NcGA%3d%3d
```

Another example:

```
<<<383047<<<BBBIVvjjeNodJzLrIJqZaw%3d%3d
```

How can I do this with a regular expression in java ?

Comment: i assumed that you're trying to do joining. Please put the input sat very first and then put the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replaceAll()` to extract the bit you want:

```
String var1 = str.replaceAll("<<<(.*?)<.*", "$1");
String var2 = str.replaceAll("<<<.*?<<<", "");
```

Comment: why `.*?`, not `.*` ?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou a) it's faster (`.*` moves the pointer all the way to the end of input then backtracks 1 char at a time until a match is found), b) it `.*?` allows for `<<<` to appear as part of the second value - ie `.*?` stops consuming as soon as a match is found, but `.*` will potentially skip over `<<<` and match a later occurrence of `<<<`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
Object Variable1;
Object Variable2;
String example = "<<<385289<<<L1S8dM4OW0VkGhKgl0NcGA%3d%3d";
String[] split = example.split( "<<<" );
for( String splittedString : split )
{
    if( splittedString.length() > 2 )
    {
        Variable1 = split[1];
        Variable2 = split[2];
    }
}
```